# .NET Core : how to read file from specific path

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have this structure :

[image]

I have files inside assets folder and I am trying to read them. I am using :

```
 public static readonly string App = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

or

```
 string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

both return `/Users/alt/Projects/MyProjects/EazyCityCore/EazyCityCA/bin/Debug/net6.0`

but assets folder is in the admin folder . How can I change the path ?

Comment: is assets a folder inside of admin folder?

Comment: is your code inside the src folder that contains two projects?

Comment: Yes, assets is inside admin and I have 2 project inside src @DongLi

Comment: where is the code your using to read the assets folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `admin` folder doesn't seem to be within your project directory, but rather somewhere else. It seems like you just manually attached it in Rider.

Your current code gets the execution directory (the bin directory), but if you want to get your project directory you can do the following:

```
var projectDirectory = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

where `projectDirectory` will be the relative path to your project directory. In your case: `/Users/alt/Projects/MyProjects/EazyCityCore/EazyCityCA`. Once you have the path to your project directory you can specify the exact location of your desired location.

You can specify that path by doing something like this:

```
var fullPath = projectDirectory + "/admin/assets/";
```

Make sure that your `admin` folder is within your project directory, and not somewhere else.